Chrome Extension detection tab fully loaded
I'm creating a Chrome extension, part of its function is to click a link of a website and the site itself will open a new tab, then my extension will print the tab. I'm now facing a problem in detecting the new tab's completeness.
My original approach is to use chrome.tabs.onUpdated and by detecting the status change to complete, the code will continue to run.
async function asyncChkTabLoaded(targetTabID){
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        chkTabLoaded = function (tabID, tabChanges, tabData) {
        if (tabID == targetTabID) {
            if ("status" in tabChanges) {
                if (tabChanges.status == "complete"){
                    resolve(tabData);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(chkTabLoaded);
    });
}
await asyncChkTabLoaded(openedTabID);

However, I found that by using this approach, part of the content is not fully loaded, mainly the images. And so the auto-print following will print a website with empty images. complete is not really meaning complete.
I believe this is due to the weird properties of the tabs.onUpdated that "The status property will cycle through "loading" and "complete"." (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/onUpdated)
I know that I can detect the loading status of the image by using image.complete. However, some of the image is a <image> tag wrapping in a <svg>, for example:
<svg id="main-svg" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid" viewBox="0 0 486 934">

<image x="0.00" y="0.00" width="486.69" height="632.84" image-rendering="-moz-crisp-edges" preserveAspectRatio="none" xlink:href="data:image/png;base64, iVB0KGgoAA..P2YII="></image>

</svg>

And it seems there's no complete attribute for svg element. So using image.complete may not fully fit my case.
So I think it is the most safetest way to use the load event of the tab window as a guideline to detect the completeness of the website contents. And here's how I modify the asyncChkTabLoaded
async function asyncChkTabLoaded(){
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        console.log("injected onload");
        console.log(document.readyState);
        sendResolve = function() {
            console.log("Window Loaded");
            resolve();
        }
        window.addEventListener("load", sendResolve);
        
    });
}
await chrome.scripting.executeScript({target : {tabId : openedTabID}, func : asyncChkTabLoaded});

However it seems like the load event will never be fired, and so the promise will never be resolved and await forever, and my code will never proceed to the next step to print.
The document.readyState is always loading. The Window Loaded can only be printed if I move the resolve() out of the function sendResolve.
So my question is how can I detect the tab load event of the new tab? I prefer to use resolve in the load event, and await the resolve, instead of putting all the follow codes into the load eventlistener callback. So my code's readability is easier and it's easier to add further code after the await.
Or how can I detect the last tab status change of tabs.onUpdated?
Or how can I detect the loading of SVG element? But that will be the least preferable way to solve this problem, as I am not sure what other unpredictable elements are still loading.
Thank you very much for your help :)
Addition info:
The new tab created by the website is created by using the following code:
var a = window.open()
a.document.open(),
a.document.write("<html>"),
a.document.write("<body >"),
a.document.write(contentForPrint),
a.document.write("</body></html>");
a.document.close(),
a.onload = function() {
    a.focus(),
    setTimeout(function() {}, 2e3)
}

The contentForPrint is a long HTML string. Not sure it can help or not

There is a dedicated and more preferable chrome.webNavigation API for your purposes. Specifically, what you're looking for chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted. The target page that is loaded will have frameId === 0. Note, however, that for SPA, the page only loads once.
// background-script
chrome.webNavigation.onCompleted.addListener(details => {
  // document, including the resources it refers to, is completely loaded and initialized
});

Don't forget to add the necessary permissions to manifest.json.
// mainfest.json
{
  "name": "My extension",
  ...
  "permissions": [
    "webNavigation"
  ],
  ...
}

UPDATED
Your project is shrouded in mystery, and it's really hard to help you without actually being able to test self ideas on the target site. However, try this option, it should work, at least it works in my tests.

We will use a content-script and try to implement it as early as possible. First, we will start with the manifest.json file:

{
  "name": "Tab Inspector",
  "version": "0.1",
  "permissions": ["tabs"],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "https://example.com*"
      ],
      "js": [
        "content.js"
      ],
      "match_about_blank": true,
      "run_at": "document_start",
      "world": "MAIN"
    }
  ],
  "manifest_version": 3
}

Let's take a closer look at the most important keys and what they are for (see additional documentation):

matches - be sure to specify the sites on which your content-script will be run, it won't work without it!
js - file where the logic will be centred and which will be connected to the landing page.
match_about_blank: true - The script will be able to inject into an about:blank frame where the parent URL matches one of the patterns declared in "matches".
run_at: document_start - the DOM is still loading. We start as early as possible.
world: MAIN - choosing the "MAIN" world means the script will share the execution environment with the host page's JavaScript. See Work in isolated worlds to learn more. We add it in case you want to patch something, like the print function, if it is accessible from the parent window.

2.Fill the content-script itself with your own logic, what and how to process, my version looks like this now:
// content.js
window.addEventListener('load', event => {
  console.log('WINDOW WAS LOADED', event);
  // start processing
});


Just tried, but it seems the images are still not loaded when resolve onComplete

That's interesting. And can you tell me briefly, you have a content script loading on a page, after all the resources are fully loaded you want to do something, right? And please give me an example, maybe you can link to the site?

Addition info: The new tab created by the website is created by using the following code:
var a = window.open()
a.document.open(),
a.document.write("");
a.document.close()

When the a.onload event is triggered, is everything loaded?

I guess yes ... At least when I see the tab, i havent had an experience that its still loading. The site has another similar script that that after all ther document.write, the onload will call the a.print automatically. And the print preview will have all the images loaded

I have an idea now. But need you to clarify. The button to open a new window is located in content script? contentForPrint is generated dynamically?

Those code of opening tab and document.write (and window.print) are all the page's script. Its not under control of my extension. But yes its a button to open the new tab. But the contentForPrint is not dynamically genetated, its a angularJS variable of the page. I believe it's generated when the page content is fetched from the server. And when print button is pressed, the string is called-up again to generate the new tab to print

Good. If it's not under your extension's control, how do you embed your content-script into the page, or do you use background + executeScript? I'm just a bit confused, to be honest. Perhaps your code is in the public domain, to see what's going on there?

My extension now has 1 content-script and 1 service-worker script. All the codes above in my question are in the service-worker.
But the "window.open() ... document.write..." are not under my extension script. It's the page itself, that I can't be controlled. And since the new tab is under URL about: blank, it's quite hard to embed a content-script into it. Otherwise I need to have the content-script to distinguish whether the tab itself is a normal page, or a blank page which generated by clicking the page's print button. The page always creates a new blank tab for different purpose.

Can you add a link to the site where you are trying to execute the script?

Not possible sorry, I want too, but it's proprietary and login is needed

Updated reply. Check this option.

Also, I'm not very sure whether it is the api's problem or the website's problem.
It seems the onCompleted is not fired every time. Sometimes the tab will just opened and loaded (as the tab is focused, that means the onload is fired), but my onCompleted still not fired and my code stopped there forever, as no resolve received. But sometimes the whole process will go through smoothly, just still no image loaded.

The code I added last doesn't use service-worker at all. Comment out all the code in service-worker, either remove the service-worker key from manifest.json. reload the extension, or better yet, reinstall it and try again.
And so yeah, there's something interesting going on with the site apparently, that's why I wanted to see what was going on.

As I said above, I prefer not to bother content-script for just detecting the window loaded or not.

One reason is that the existing content-script has already tons of function. And the program flow before and after detecting the tab loaded arr all in the service-worker. If putting this back to the content-script, I need tosend message back and forth

Another reason of not using content-script is that I need to have the content-script to distinguish whether the tab itself is a normal page, or a blank page which generated by clicking the page's print button. The page always creates a new blank tab for different purposes, printing purpose is just one of the many purposes. And to detecting what purpose is the tab, I need to keep tracking the button that the user clicked before the tab is opened.

And I prefer not to mix the two worlds. During the development, i was tempted to mix them a few times and eventually I didn't. So prefer not this time either

Your logic is flawed. It is just fine to have a content-script that communicates with the service-worker via the message system, it was invented and is recommended for use. In addition, you may have not just one content-script, but several, for different pages with different logic. I also wanted to add that without using content-script it is unrealistic to say which of the buttons was pressed by the user. So you should think about it.

What you are writing about looks like you have come up with one way to do what you want and are backing everything else up with crutches. If the solution via service-worker cannot be made to work properly and the result is not as expected, you should try another way.
